# Не знаю как правильно ввести значение в char с помощью scanf

Tags: c

Есть задача, сделать через функцию вывод квадрата, и при этом задать ему сторону и из каких символов будет построен. Всё сделал не могу понять причину чего оно не работает, почему после введения стороны сразу программа завершается. делаю из Win 7 x64, DevC++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void even(int side, char symbol);

main()
{

  int side = 0;
  char symbol;
  printf("Vvedite storony - ");
  scanf("%d", &side);

  printf("Vvedite symbol - ");
  scanf("%c", &symbol);

  even(side, symbol);

  system("PAUSE");
}

void even(int i, char symbol)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
  {
    for (int m = 1; m <= i; m++)
    {
    printf("%c", symbol);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return;
}
```

upd. проблема в

```
printf("Vvedite symbol - ");
scanf("%c", &symbol);
```

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что программа не закрывается потому, что просто отработала до конца? Поставьте точку останова на последней фигурной скобке функции `main`.
2. А что происходит, если вы не считываете значения переменных из консоли, а задаёте их прямо в коде?
3. Ваш заголовок вопроса отдаёт сенсационностью.

Comment: Программа отрабатывает до конца, 2 - программа правильно отрабатывает, тогда дело в самом вводе информации printf("Vvedite symbol - ");
  scanf("%c", &symbol);=
3 - Сейчас изменю, чтобы никто не думал, что у меня "нездоровая сенсационность".

Comment: @steelhouse: давайте я предположу, что вы вводите числа через Enter, правильно?

Comment: ээээ да, логику уловил судя по всему, а как мне сделать, чтобы не через ентер, а то оно и считывает последний символ, что является в данном случае именно он..

Comment: @dzhioev: круто, не знал, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, кажется понял, что вызвало Ваше удивление, когда я написал о возврате NULL из `skipnl()`.

Естественно, "вперед" этот макрос не заглядывает.  

Если вдруг кто-то захочет, то можно так 

    #define skipnleof() ({ char b[1024], *res = NULL; fgets(b,1024,stdin); \
            int c = getchar(); if (c != EOF) { ungetc(c,stdin); res = b; } \
            res; })

и `oops` не появится. Конечно 1) форматировать в комментариях трудно; 

2) такое заглядывание вперед для unbuffered IMHO работать не будет.

Comment: @avp: я имел в виду такое: http://pastebin.com/uXvacCyL

---
сорри, неправильный пример. вот правильный: http://pastebin.com/LrJF0i2b

---
@avp: ох, почитал документацию и понял, почему надо так сложно, и почему простой `feof` не катит. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, что происходит.

Пусть вы ввели с клавиатуры `13 <Enter> x <Enter>`.

В вашем потоке stdin находятся такие символы: `1 3 \n x \n`.

Первый `scanf` "забирает" цифры 1 и 3 из потока, и останавливается на первой не-цифре: `\n`.

Следующий `scanf` читает просто один символ из потока, им оказывается как раз `\n`.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/i9xXXr

---

Делайте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248017/276994):

1. Читайте строки с клавиатуры полностью, используя `fgets`;
2. Вытаскивайте из них информацию при помощи `sscanf`.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/aNNng3):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define INPUT_BUF_SIZE 256

int main(void)
{
    int d;
    char c;
    char buf[INPUT_BUF_SIZE];
    fgets(buf, INPUT_BUF_SIZE, stdin); // читаем целую строку
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &d);             // достаём из неё число
    fgets(buf, INPUT_BUF_SIZE, stdin); // читаем целую строку
    sscanf(buf, "%c", &c);             // достаём из неё символ
    printf("d = %d, c = %c = char(%d)", d, c, (int)c);
    return 0; 
}
```

`fgets` читает всю строку (точнее, её кусок, который влазит в буфер), включая и финальный `\n`, если он есть.

Comment: Понятно, правда, я всё равно не могу решить, буду дальше думать.

upd: Спасибо не мой уровень, это ещё предстоит мне выучить) Спасибо большое.

Comment: @steelhouse: добавил пример.

Comment: @steelhouse: пожалуйста! Видите, там всё просто, потратьте 5 минут, разберитесь, будете объяснять другим потом :-)

Comment: До этого очень далеко) Проблема в том, что делаю упражнения из книги, а там ещё не дошли до такого, а задания подобного типа уже есть. Данное решение по книги не прибегаю к более интересным и продвинутым решениям, можно обойти как я понял просто поменяв ввод данных местами (только что дошло), а вот что касается примера, я его запомню, всё пригодится) И заодно выучу новые функции.. Ну а до stdin ещё не добрался. Спасибо ещё раз, очень хорошо объяснили)

Comment: @steelhouse: Подробно разбирать все упражнения в книге — очень хороший метод выучить язык. Удачи вам!

Comment: Есть простой способ "сглатывания" `'\n'` вместе с пробелами и проч. до конца строки при вводе scanf-ом.

    #define skipnl() ({ char b[1024]; fgets(b,1024,stdin); })

Кстати, `skipnl()` возвращает результат - NULL при конце файла.

Comment: @avp: _возвращает_? это такое специальное расширение синтаксиса C, или я отстал от <s>жизни</s> развития стандарта?

---
Кстати, fgets не вернёт NULL, если ей был считан финальный `\n` в файле, так что логика "`skipnl()` не вернул NULL — значит, не конец файла" была бы не верна.

Comment: Не понял. 

Замените system("pause"); в программе автора на


      while (skipnl())
        puts("make Eof"), fflush(stdout);

и получите (gcc -std=gnu99 ttt.c)

    C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>a
    Vvedite storony - 2
    Vvedite symbol - 8
    88
    88
    make Eof
    ^Z
    
    C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>

в консоли Windows 7

Comment: @VladD, это нестандартное расширение gcc. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html
Блок, заключенный в скобочки, возвращает значение последнего, заключенного в него, выражения.